# Facebook Login. The OpenId service doesn't provide enough user info

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, https, openid

Greetings dear programmers. Recently i have tryed to add facebook login to my Web application. I have registred my app on [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/). But there is a problem. I can login to my app via facebook but other user can not. Facebook don't want to return e-mail adress of user. But i need it to know.

Here is information sent by facebook.

```
base {System.Dynamic.DynamicObject} = {"id":"158353287673184","first_name":"Andrew","gender":"male","last_name":"Miller","link":"https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/158353287673184/","locale":"ru_RU","name":"Andrew Miller","timezone":3,"updated_time":"2014-06-20T09:34:03+0000"}
```

as you can see. There is no e-mail.

Can someone explain me. What the matter with the responce from facebook? I have cheked all preferences of my Application in facebook twice. but nothing have changed...

And i wonder to know, is it issues with my application or with facebook?

Thanks for replies!

---

Best regards,
Andrew Miller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forget to ask facebook about it
try add scope="email" to your request

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&state=SOME_ARBITRARY_BUT_UNIQUE_STRING&scope=email
```